Python JWT-Extended 4.7.1 release Pytest Errors
for a project we had a lot of PyTest's written for a school project and now have 15 of them failing. Apparantly JWT-Extended updated today, would anyone know if the compatibility between any of these is causing the error. Any help would be appreciated, I'll send one test that was failing (for context they passed yesterday and not today on Github Actions no changes made.
import pytest
import sys
import os
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

bcrypt = Bcrypt()
#adds relative paths so that it can access the models in backend
project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.insert(0, project_root)

#imports the models requried for testing, if you would like to test another model, import it here
from db.db_setup import db, create_app, User, Ticket
from hello import app as flask_app
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

bcrypt = Bcrypt(flask_app)

#Creates a temporary database for testing using the user model
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_client():
    flask_app.config['TESTING'] = True
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'


    with flask_app.app_context():
        #The first drop all is required to flush the the db incase the second drop all fails
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        #Directly creates admin user in the database
        admin_user = User(
            email='admin@example.com',
            firstName='Admin',
            lastName='User',
            password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash('admin_password'),
            isAdmin=True
        )
        db.session.add(admin_user)
        db.session.commit()
        with flask_app.test_client() as testing_client:
            yield testing_client

        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

#tests creating a user using the POST API
def test_create_user_without_authentication(test_client):
        response = test_client.post('/users', json={'email': 'test_user@example.com', 'firstName': 'Test', 'lastName': 'User', 'password': 'password', 'isAdmin': True})
        assert response.status_code == 401
    
#test getting a user using the GET API
def test_get_user_without_authentication(test_client):
        response = test_client.get('/users')
        assert response.status_code == 401

#test a login with invalid credentials
def test_login_invalid(test_client):
    response = test_client.post('/login', json={'email': 'test_user2@example.com', 'password': 'wrong_password'})
    assert response.status_code == 401
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Invalid credentials'}

#Logs in as admin user
def test_delete_non_existent_user(test_client):
        test_client.post('/login', json={'email': 'admin@example.com', 'password': 'admin_password'})
        response = test_client.delete('/users/delete', json={'userId' : '100'})
        assert response.status_code == 404
        assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'User not found'}

#tests creating a user using the POST API
def test_create_user(test_client):
        response = test_client.post('/users', json={'email': 'test_user2@example.com', 'firstName': 'Test2', 'lastName': 'User2', 'password': 'password', 'isAdmin': False})
        test_client.post('/users', json={'email': 'test_user@example.com', 'firstName': 'Test', 'lastName': 'User', 'password': 'password', 'isAdmin': False})
        assert response.status_code == 201
        assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'User created successfully'}

        user = User.query.filter_by(email='test_user@example.com').first()
        assert user.password != 'password'

#test getting a user using the GET API
def test_get_user(test_client):
    response = test_client.get('/users')
        
    users = response.get_json()

    user1 = next((user for user in users if user['id'] == 1), None)
    
    assert user1 is not None
    assert user1 == {'id': 1, 'email': 'admin@example.com', 'firstName': 'Admin', 'lastName': 'User', 'isAdmin': True}

# Test case for changing the password of the user
def test_change_password(test_client):
    # Assuming the user with id 1 exists from the previous test
    response = test_client.put('/users/1/password', json={'password': 'new_password'})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Password updated successfully'}

def test_delete_existent_user(test_client):
        response = test_client.delete('/users/delete', json={'userId' : '3'})
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'User with id 3 deleted successfully'}

# Logout the user
def test_logout_after_delete(test_client):
    response = test_client.post('/logout')
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Logout successful'}

def test_login_deleted_account(test_client):
    response = test_client.post('/login', json={'email': 'test_user@example.com', 'password': 'password'})
    assert response.status_code == 401

#test a login with valid credentials, the cookie is stored in the testing client, if the cookie isn't returned, then the test_protected_endpoint will fail
def test_login_valid(test_client):
    response = test_client.post('/login', json={'email': 'test_user2@example.com', 'password': 'password'})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Login successful'}

# Access the protected endpoint. Checks if the endpoints works and if a JWT Token is created and stored on login.
def test_protected_endpoint(test_client):
    response = test_client.get('/protected')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Access granted'}

# Access the username endpoint. Checks if the username is returned correctly.
def test_username(test_client):
    response = test_client.get('/name')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.get_json() == {'name': 'Test2'}

def test_delete_non_admin(test_client):
        response = test_client.delete('/users/delete', json={'userId' : '1'})
        assert response.status_code == 403
        assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Admin privileges required to delete users'}

#tests creating a user using the POST API
def test_create_user_without_admin(test_client):
        response = test_client.post('/users', json={'email': 'test_user@example.com', 'firstName': 'Test', 'lastName': 'User', 'password': 'password', 'isAdmin': True})
        assert response.status_code == 403
        assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Admin privileges required to create users'}
    
#test getting a user using the GET API
def test_get_user_without_admin(test_client):
        response = test_client.get('/users')
        assert response.status_code == 403
        assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Admin privileges required to view all users'}

# Logout the user
def test_logout(test_client):
    response = test_client.post('/logout')
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Logout successful'} 

# Attempt to access the protected endpoint without a cookie
def test_protected_endpoint_after_logout(test_client):
    response = test_client.get('/protected')
    assert response.status_code == 401

# Attempt to login using changed password
def test_login_with_changed_password(test_client):
    response = test_client.post('/login', json={'email': 'admin@example.com', 'password': 'new_password'})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.get_json() == {'message': 'Login successful'}

^First part of the test file that is having failures
Flask==2.3.2
flask-cors
#mysql-connector-python
pytest
python-dotenv
SQLAlchemy
Flask_SQLAlchemy
pymysql
cryptography
Flask-Migrate
flask-bcrypt
Flask-JWT-Extended
werkzeug==2.3.8

Any help would be appreciated, me and my team have been looking for hours.
